# Animated Vector plot

Tags: plotting, animation, vector

I'm trying to make an animation of a time-varying 2D vector field. However, I'm got a difficulty in that *Mathematica* normalises the length of the vectors with each call to `VectorPlot`.

A (very simple) example:

```
myField = {Cos[2 π t], 0};

Animate[
        VectorPlot[myField /. t -> TT, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}],
        {TT, 0, 1}]
```

Expected result:
The arrows grow and shrink in time

The actual result:
The arrows remain the same size, but flick direction

Is there some way to fix the length of the arrows relative to the field value?

Comment: You've seen `VectorScale`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Ox4A4D mentioned in the comment, you could use the option `VectorScale` to set the length of vectors, here is an example code:

```
myField = {Cos[2 \[Pi] t], 0};
Animate[VectorPlot[myField /. t -> TT, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
          VectorScale -> Abs[0.05 Cos[2 Pi TT]]], {TT, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Ah, I see -- it's making use of the fact that you know what the maximum value is with this simple function. Perhaps that will put me on the right track...

Answer (score 6):

With a slightly more interesting function, and cleaner syntax:

```
myField[x_, y_, t_] := {Cos[2 Pi x t], Sin[2 Pi y t]};

Animate[VectorPlot[myField[x, y, t], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  VectorScale -> {Small, 1, None}], {t, 0, 1}]
```

Check the documentation and play around with the arguments to `VectorScale` as required.

**EDIT:**

I had indeed misunderstood your requirements. mm.Jang's answer is what you're looking for. `0.05*Norm[myField[t]]` should generalize it.

Comment: Your code somehow doesn't work for me... I'm using MMA 9.0.1.0 by the way...

Comment: Any error? I'm on 9.0.0.0 on 64-bit Linux.

Comment: @RodLm you must run `Clear[myField];` first.

Comment: @CoreyKelly Yes, when I run your code nothing happens. I mean, the slider t moves itself but no vector plot is shown.

Comment: @mm.Jang Thank you... problem solved! Corey, please forget what I've written before.

Comment: Well, this isn't the same problem, because your vectors are the same length at all times (and in fact, all space too)