# Animating a Vector Field

Tags: plotting, animation, vector

I am trying to create animations of a time dependent vector field $\vec v(t,x,y)$. The problem is that `VectorPlot` scales the vectors for each time $ t $ separately based on the minimal and maximal norm of the vector field at that time.

[This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26813/animated-vector-plot) shows how to solve this problem using `VectorScale` in the case in which the ratio of the max. norm for some time $ t$ and the  the max. norm over all times is known. I suppose this could be found by evaluating $ \vec v $ on a $ (t,x,y) $ grid, but that makes for quite a lot of evaluations which I'd rather avoid. Surely there is a simpler way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the time to revisit this problem. In the end, I went with determining the correct scaling factors manually. The code below takes a vector field (as a function $v(t,x,y)$), $x$ & $y$ ranges, $t$ range & number of frames as arguments and produces an array of suitably scaled vector plots. The range of scale parameters can be set with Options, as can all the default `VectorPlot` directives.

```
Options[vecAnimate] = {
   "scaleMin" -> 0.01, "scaleMax" -> 0.075, 
   "vecScaleFun" -> Automatic
   };
vecAnimate[v_, {x_, xmin_, xmax_}, {y_, ymin_, ymax_}, {tmin_, tmax_, 
   nFrames_}, opt : OptionsPattern[{vecAnimate, VectorPlot}]] :=

 Module[{
   evalPoints =  
    Reap[VectorPlot[v[0, x, y], {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}, 
       EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, y}]]][[-1, 1]],
   tR = Subdivide[tmin, tmax, nFrames][[;; -2]],
   scaleMin = OptionValue["scaleMin"], 
   scaleMax = OptionValue["scaleMax"],
   maxNorms, totalMaxNorm, scales 
   },
  maxNorms = Table[Max @ (Norm /@ (v[t, #1, #2] & @@@ evalPoints)), {t, tR}];
  totalMaxNorm = Max @ maxNorms;
  scales = maxNorms/totalMaxNorm;
  scales = scales * (scaleMax - scaleMin) + scaleMin;
  MapThread[
   VectorPlot[v[#1, x, y], {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}, 
     VectorScale -> {#2, Automatic, OptionValue["vecScaleFun"]}, 
     Evaluate@FilterRules[{opt}, Options[VectorPlot]]] &, {tR, scales}]
  ]
```

Demo (Hertzian Dipole):

```
With[{ex = 5, r = Sqrt[#.#] &, 
  d0 = {0, 1}}, {v = Function[{t, x, y}, If[r[{x, y}] > .75, 
     Cos[t - r[{x, y}]] (d0/r[{x, y}] - ( {x, y}*({x, y}.d0))/r[{x, y}]^3),
     {0, 0}]]
 }, 
 ListAnimate[
  vecAnimate[v, {x, -ex, ex}, {y, -ex, ex}, {0, 2 \[Pi], 30}, 
   PlotRange -> 1.2 {{-ex, ex}, {-ex, ex}}]
 ]
]
```

yields

[image: gif]

The method above fails in the presence of poles. As in the example, this can be alleviated by just returning a zero vector in some region or above some vector field norm.

Answer (score 1):

Try `VectorScale` this way:

```
Animate[
 VectorPlot[{Cos[2 \[Pi] x + t], Sin[2 \[Pi] y + t^2]},
  {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
  VectorScale -> {Large, Scaled[1]}],
 {t, .1, 2, .05}]
```

Comment: But e.g. with the vector field `1/t {Cos[2 \[Pi] x + t], Sin[2 \[Pi] y + t^2]}`, this will not reproduce the shrinking vector magnitudes correctly, which is what I am after.